# A meteor strikes Earth: what problem does it cause a thousand years later?

Tags: environment, earth-like

So it finally happened: a giant meteor struck the earth.  Not large enough to kill everyone, but large enough to cause widespread devastation.

In moments, a shockwave destroyed everything near the impact site.

In the first few hours, earthquakes caused massive devastation to the entire region.

Over the next day, the tsunami caused by the impact reached coastlines around the world, pummeling cities and drowning whole civilizations.

Then, over a few weeks or months, the sky remained darkened by debris from the impact, which in turn causes reduced crop yields around the world (in areas where there still are crops, of course).

**What problem would show up a thousand years later?**

(The "thousand years" here is a *very* rough number.)

---

I'm specifically looking for a problem that

- isn't present continuously from the time of the impact,
- first occurs or grows in strength a thousand years later,
- and isn't just "more meteorites".

Comment: This feels... very plot-centric. I would say it was purely idea-generation, but we no longer have a close reason for that. Honestly, anything big enough to cause that level of devastation is, more or less, going to remove anything that would be intelligent enough to care.

Comment: Does radioactivity constitute a viable answer, since it will do is over time and be a constant danger? What about new diseases and microbes the object carried to earth? Is there really an objective way to gauge these answers?

Comment: If the impact is severe enough the major problem a thousand years later might be that all life is still extinct.

Answer (score 2):

Alien plague...   The meteor had a primitive, invasive life form inside which was nearly annihilated by the planetary impact.  A few cells survived however, and they have been multiplying and mutating, adapting to rules of Earth's indigenous life.

It took hundreds of years to infest a single field of plant life.

From there, it was ingested into grazing animals and took more centuries becoming infectious and learning how to jump the species barrier.

Now, a thousand years later, it has jumped into humans, turning its new hosts into...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're assuming there will be some survivors to repopulate the earth...

Are social issues fair game? A thousand years after the meteorite struck, a cult arises among some of the descendants of the survivors, claiming that the destruction on earth was not some kind "rock from space" but was actually a supernatural judgement (note: this need not be the first group making such claims, but perhaps the first that attracts any significant following). This quickly becomes a popular belief and a series of wars/crusades/jihads are waged in an effort to convert the non-believers.

If you want to stick to environmental factors, you might imagine that the darkened skies kicked off an ice age, which is now ending after a thousand years. This means sea levels are rising, weather patterns are changing, ice damns are breaking (leading to massive [megafloods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outburst_flood)), and whole species of animals are going extinct.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of *indirect* results. They could matter in any apocalyptic rebuilding.

- A neglected hazardous material store finally fails. It could be a missile silo which finally rusting through, chemicals which slowly made their way into an aquifier for a thousand years and now arrive at the well, etc.
- Mankind has recovered enough knowledge and population to re-industrialize, but all easily accessible iron and coal deposits are gone.